# Undefined method and routing errors takes a lot of time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

Since I updated my application from Rails 2.3.5 to Rails 3, currently running 3.2.1, undefined method and routing errors take a lot of time. Every time I have some method missing my Macbook Pro is freezing and after 3/4 minutes I get the corresponding error.

Here you have a full stack trace when I have an undefined method, the thing that is strange is that the diagnostics.erb takes 149863 ms to load, this is not normal I guess :

https://gist.github.com/1778939

The only call on application level that is in the stack trace is the method_missing in my application_controller.rb, here is the method I'm using :

```
def method_missing(method_id, *arguments)
  # Define a authorize_type dynamic authorization thingiemagiggy
  if match = /authorize_([_a-zA-Z]+)/.match(method_id.to_s)
    return authorize(match[1])
  else
    super
  end
end
```

I also will add a stack trace of a routing error, there it seems that the views take ages to load, but there is just a link to in this views:

https://gist.github.com/1779027

Somebody can explain me why the launching of this kind of errors takes so much time and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found out how to fix it with the help of the rails issue on github : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1525

I made an initializer anti_freeze.rb that contains :

```
module ActionDispatch
  module Routing
    class RouteSet
      alias inspect to_s
    end
  end
end
```